# Insert User Defined Data Table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Below is the stored proc i have so far I keep getting this error when executed: 
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure db_recession_band_dates_save, Line 18
Must declare the scalar variable "@dates".

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dates_Save]
@Loc VARCHAR(75),
@dates StartEndDateType READONLY  
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @id int
SELECT @id = MYINTFIELD FROM date_locations
IF @id IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO db_recession_bands VALUES (@loc)
    SET @id = @@IDENTITY
END
INSERT INTO db_recession_band_dates VALUES (@id,@dates)      
END
```

Comment: What is the typical value of @dates? (e.g. if you debug your sp)

Comment: @dates comes from a DataTable type, where one column is a start date and the other column is an end date.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this sp?

Comment: as I said -- you treat @dates as if it were a table then. At the moment you are treating it as a scalar value (just as the error message says)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if StartEndDateType is a user defined table type then you treat it as if it were a table.

Change this:

```
INSERT INTO db_recession_band_dates VALUES (@id,@dates)
```

Into something like

```
INSERT INTO db_recession_band_dates (<COLUMN LIST>) -- don't do blind inserts it will hurt you at some point in the future
SELECT @id, <COLUMN LIST>
FROM @dates
```